# What's the best way to show "focus" in a grid?

Tags: grid

I'm drawing a standard grid view with rows and columns, but I want to do something unique and interesting to mark the focused or selected cell.  Any ideas?  The dotted-line rectangle is out.  :)

Answer (score 1):

Allow me to through an idea - hook the onfocus/onclick client events of the gridview cells and apply your css classes or some kind of jQuery animation when those events are raised.

Comment: Well, that's pretty much what I'm doing, but I'm looking for ideas about *what* to draw/animate in the cell. Like (for example) making the text of the selected cell bold (lame) or drawing a dotted-line rectangle around the inside of the cell (also lame).